# Add a key binding for opening the whole "right + click" menu in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to add a key binding for opening the "right + click" menu in VSCode to my `keybindings.json` so it can be opened without the mouse.

I'm on a Mac computer which means the `menu` key between `alt` & `ctrl` on the right-hand side doesn't exist.

I've searched through the web but I'm not even sure if I'm using the right terms cause nothing relevant comes up. I'd like to open **the whole menu/pop window** highlighted in the screenshot below instead of just "Go to Definition", Peek, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`Shift` + `F10`

The `fn` key is in the bottom left of the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that help me find the right command and now I can add a custom key binding:
    {
        "key": "alt+enter",
        "command": "editor.action.showContextMenu",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }